# Setting up Rasbian, WI-FI connexion and SSH directly into the SD card

Tags: raspbian, ssh, sd-card

I would like to set-up everything on my Raspberry Pi Zero (WI-FI and SSH) without the need of a keyboard and monitor, and I was wondering if I could do it directly from my main PC into the SD card, so that when I boot the RPi, everything is there and working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add two files to your boot partition: One called `wpa_supplicant.conf` which contains something like:

```
country=US 
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    ssid="your_real_wifi_ssid"
    psk="your_real_password"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

and one called `ssh` to enable the ssh service.

It's not that hard to find this information by using a search engine: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/headless.md

Comment: You don't need `key_mgmt=WPA-PSK` but you do need `country=US` to have the correct ISO country code for where in the world you're located.

Answer (score 1):

This github project aims is a "The minimal Raspbian unattended netinstaller for Raspberry Pi".

So it will not only setup WiFi and SSH it can change stuff like packages to install, keyboard layout and lot more.

https://github.com/FooDeas/raspberrypi-ua-netinst